# Persist Variable value from inner class to the outside world

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have the following code:

```
String response1;
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                response1 = response;
 //This log gives result
                Log.d("volley", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.d("volley", error.toString());
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
  //This log give null pointer exception
        Log.d(TAG, response1);
 //How I can make sth like this:
 String [] data = doSthWithThisValue(response1)
```

As described in the code the the variable response1 gives result inside Response.Listener class. I want to use this value outside this inner class. How I can do this?
I have read some posts to declare the variable as final

Comment: `response1 = response;` should be a compile error... Is this your real exact code?

Comment: In fact, you cannot access variables inside an anonymous class from an outer scope that is not _effectively_ final. Thus, the assignment to `response1` must produce a compiler error. Please post compilable code. Or maybe this isn't your current code?

Comment: There isn't even a question mark in your post.

Comment: I would like to persist the value of response1 from inside innerclass to the outside world after it is being filled. How I can do this?

Comment: There are lots of ways, depending on what you're trying to do (for example, how many things will be using it, do you want to store the response or just do something immediately with it and then forget it, and so on).

Comment: @James I get a json string in the response, I send it to a function to parse it and return array of strings that would populate a listview.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems that you are using `Android-Volley`  to handle network request.So 
`onResponse` will be called after getting correct response(status OK) from server.

And you want to print the value of `response1`,which calls before `onResponse` function called,i.e. you print log value of `response1` before setting value in it.

So use `Log.d(TAG, response1);` in `onResponse` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you posted, nothing is calling the inner class method onResponse which is where response1 is getting set.  You are creating the inner class and then almost immediately calling onResponse.  I assume onResponse is supposed to be called by some sort of network event.